# How do I concatenate html and php?

Tags: php

I currently have this:

```
    $output .= '
    <tr>
    <th style="text-align: left">'.(__("Item", "WSPSC")).'</th><th>'.(__("Quantity", "WSPSC")).'</th><th>'.(__("Price", "WSPSC")).'</th><th></th>
    </tr>';
```

But I need to replace **Item** with a piece of php like:

```
$output .= '
    <tr>
    <th style="text-align: left">'.(__("
     <?php if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'); ?>
         Item
     <?php elseif(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='it'); ?>
        Products
     <?php endif; ?>
        ", "WSPSC")).'</th><th>'.(__("Quantity", "WSPSC")).'</th><th>'.(__("Price", "WSPSC")).'</th><th></th>
    </tr>';
```

The issue I am having is that this is obviously wrong but I can't get my head around the correct concatenation of html and php

Comment: The php string concatenation operation is `.` You should set a variable with either `item` or `products` and then include it in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I right understand you need something like this:

```
$output .= '
    <tr>
    <th style="text-align: left">'.
( 
  (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en')? 
    'Item': 
    ( (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='it')? 'Products': '' ), 
  "WSPSC"
)
.'</th><th>'.(__("Quantity", "WSPSC")).'</th><th>'.(__("Price", "WSPSC")).'</th><th></th>
    </tr>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use it in that way. Look at this pseudo code:

```
$output .= '
<tr>
<th style="text-align: left">';


if (something...) {
   $output.= 'sss';
} 
elseif (something...) {
   $output.= 'ddd'; 
}
```

That's the way you should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your replies helped me thanks, this worked:

```
$output .= '
<tr>
<th style="text-align: left">';
if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en') {
    $output .= (__("Item", "WSPSC"));
} elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='it') {
    $output .= (__("PRODOTTO", "WSPSC"));
}
$output .= '</th><th>'.(__("Quantity", "WSPSC")).'</th><th>'.(__("Price", "WSPSC")).'</th><th></th>
</tr>';
```

Comment: Strange, so you first removed my accepted answer, then accepted your answer, and now you accepted someone else answer :)

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek nevermind man, to be honest I used my own answer at the end therefore it would have been normal to accept mine. but don't worry, re accepted yours and put a thumb up ;)

Comment: You can do whatever you want, but for me it's quite strange that you unaccept answer after over 2 months. Never seen that before